# Any way to use a VLOOKUP formula in Numbers to insert an image instead of text value?

Tags: numbers

The intent is to create a sheet that references orders from customers with an image of each item ordered from my catalog of inventory.

I need to create a spreadsheet that references item SKUs to display an image of a unique item. For example: 004 entered in cell A:1 should lookup 004 on sheet "images" and return the value in column 2 that matches 004. I have successfully created this formula using the VLOOKUP function.

However, I want Numbers to populate the image in the resulting cell. The way my formula currently works it will only return the text in the cell. How do I get it to return the image value? If I delete the text out of the cell corresponding to 004 the result returned is 0 even though there is an image pasted into the cell.

Current formula:

```
VLOOKUP($A2,images::Table 1::A$1:B$10,2,FALSE)
```

I had dragged images from the Finder into cells but it appears as though they only show up as background images in the cells or something like that.

[image: Test sheet with Formula]
[image: Test inventory image sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The images aren't the actual content of the cell, they're just cell formatting (background image), and formula cannot interact with formatting, only with cell contents.
- Conditional formatting can only apply a restricted set of formatting options and unfortunately images are not one of these.
- AppleScript does not provide the ability to set [cell background images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RIO6.png), only [cell background colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RIO6.png) (even though shapes and text items do have the ability for background images).

Therefore currently this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was afraid of that. I'm not very familiar with AppleScript but I was wondering then if there would be a way to use AppleScript to do what I am looking for. Any idea?

Comment: @Jeremy Unfortunately it's not possible to set cell background images with AppleScript, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky way to get this done:

- Take your images table and overlay it on the test sheet.
- Enlarge the row widths so they are all the same.
- Add a formula to the images table that checks the test sheet if the SKU is present.  This could be in a separate hidden cell or in the image cell itself with transparent text:
  [image: Column Match Formula]
- Filter the image table for True results
  [image]
- Hide all cells besides the Column B, (or use transparent results)

Keep in mind that Test Sheet row A has to be sorted ascending for this to work with no duplicates. Alternatively, you can have multiple horizontal tables of overlapping rows one to test each SKU for a match. Finally, if you're at liberty to use cardinal numbers for SKUs you can substitute empty Row() or Column() to stand in for SKU references.
[image]